# How do I setMaskfilter without crash on Android O?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I use a RecyclerView in my grid. Each item has textview and Imageview. 
I set mask filter for textview in my Adapter as below:

```
float[] direction = new float[]{0.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f};
MaskFilter maskFilter = new EmbossMaskFilter(direction, 0.8f, 15f, 1f);
holder.textview.getPaint().setMaskFilter(maskFilter);
```

It is the reason of crash (`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xfff8022c in tid 32638 (ReferenceQueueD)`) for the firs time run.

Answer (score 0):

This is known [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73785759#comment4).
Problem in method `canvas.drawText();`
But I found a way to avoid crash, by using `canvas.drawPath();` instead.

```
Path path = new Path();
paint.getTextPath( text, 0, text.length(), x, y, path );
canvas.drawPath( path, paint );
```

If you want to use it in TextView you have to extend this class and create new onDraw method.
Enjoy!