# EmbossMaskFilter causes App CRASH on Android OS 8.1(Oreo), 9.0(Pie), rest working perfect

Tags: android, android-studio

**EmbossMaskFilter** causes App CRASH on Android OS 8.1(Oreo), 9.0(Pie), rest working perfect on all other OS. Came to know when a user of Samsung Note 9 reported the issue.

Developers Guide:

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/EmbossMaskFilter

```
float[] direction = new float[] {0.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f};

EmbossMaskFilter filter = new EmbossMaskFilter(
                        direction, // direction of the light source
                        0.5f, // ambient light between 0 to 1
                        1, // specular highlights
                        1f // blur before applying lighting
                );

textView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
textView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
```

App crashes on API > 25

While there is no issue on devices  API <= 25

As per documentation (aforementioned link):

*This constructor was deprecated in API level 28.
This subclass is not supported and should not be instantiated.*

Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `App crashes` with exception and stacktrace which you have to provide

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, Testing on Emulator gives followings exceptions:
A/libc: Invalid address 0xca37b800 passed to free: value not allocated
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa0b7e4fc in tid 11949

if comment this statement,
textView.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
then no app crash and thus, no text emboss effect applies.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578296/how-do-i-setmaskfilter-without-crash-on-android-o/55186683#55186683